# Unknown data out at Azure Mobile Service

Tags: c#, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have some unexplainable data coming from my Azure Mobile Service.

There is a method that is called every 30 seconds and returns a HTTP status of 200.

```
public class InboxController : ApiController
{
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Set(Container container)
    {            
        // Magic happens ... (SQL Inserts and Notifications)
        return new StatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK, this);
    }
}
```

The SQL Database and Notification Hub are in the same Azure region.

[image]

**28.8 MB Data Out**

Where is this data coming from?

Answer (score 0):

I notice there's a single HTTP Error listed in the middle of that graph after which the data out spikes.  Could you have a leak in your code somewhere which is causing a large result to be returned (even though you might discard it)?

Seeing the SQL logic you removed might help explain this a little.

Data Out indicates data egress that is seen leaving Azure (this includes cross-region traffic).

Is this the only method in your API?